# corosync & pacemaker master / slave VIP

Tags: pacemaker, corosync

I'm looking for a way to have a master/slave fail-over that share 2 common virtual-IPs (on Ubuntu):

- vip1: 10.0.0.171
- vip2: 10.0.0.172
- master: 10.0.0.181
- slave: 10.0.0.182

**I need the following functionality**:

- If both master & slave machines are up, master gets both VIPs
- If master goes down, slave gets *both* VIPs
- If master goes back up, it gets back *both* VIPs
- If only master is up, well, master gets the VIPs (of course.)

I was able to achieve this easily with heartbeat, but it seems like corosync+pacemaker is "the future."  Unfortunately, finding good, concise documentation has proven difficult for me to find...

**This is my heartbeat setup:**

/etc/hosts:

```
10.0.0.181  master-host
10.0.0.182  slave-host
```

/etc/ha.d/ha.cf:

```
deadtime 3
warntime 5
initdead 10
bcast eth0
auto_failback on
node master-host
node slave-host
use_logd yes
```

/etc/ha.d/haresources:

```
master-host IPaddr::10.0.0.171/24/eth0 IPaddr::10.0.0.172/24/eth0
```

**As a bonus** (something that heartbeat seems to be unable to do on its own) it would be nice to be able to:

- Have both the master & slave be unaware of one another (i.e. they don't know each other IPs)

  - they can share a password
  - each knows if it's a master or a slave

**Extra bonus**:

- being able to add a second slave, such as slave: 10.0.0.183

Is this something that can be accomplished with corosync & pacemaker?